# How to find the starting values in a Fixed-point iteration

Tags: numerical-methods, fixed-point-theorems, numerical-calculus

Hi I have to find which of the following equations and for which starting values converges towards a fixed point.

The equations are:

$ a) x = e^x−sin(x)+x$

$b) x = sin(x) − e^x + x$

$c) x = arcsin(e^x), x < 0$

$d) x = ln(sin(x)), x ∈ (0, π)$

I know how to find out if a fixed point iteration converges towards a fixed point but the problem is that I really don't know how to find the starting values.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

The fixed point theorem involves an interval $[a,b]$. Once you are able to establish the conditions of the theorem in a given interval, you can just pick **any** initial condition in that interval.

Obviously, this strategy will give admissible starting points but will not rule out other starting points outside the interval $[a,b]$.

Comment: and how can I find $[a,b]$? Sorry for the late reply